NextJS 14 / React 18 post upgrade error: TypeError: can't access property "useState", dispatcher is null
I'm in a NextJS app that I've recently upgraded from NextJS 12 to 14, and upgraded React from 16 to 18... plus a bunch of other libraries. It's been a trek, and all the things are upgraded.
I am getting the following error on the frontend (but not on SSR).
TypeError: can't access property "useState", dispatcher is null
const UseModal = () => {
> 4 |   const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState<boolean>(false);

and in other places:
TypeError: can't access property "useEffect", dispatcher is null
Google and openai tell me that I may have multiple versions of react.
However I am using the resolutions package.json field with Yarn 4 and believe I have ensured this isn't the case:
yarn info react
└─ react@npm:18.3.1
   ├─ Version: 18.3.1
   │
   └─ Dependencies
      └─ loose-envify@npm:^1.1.0 → npm:1.4.0

yarn info react-dom
└─ react-dom@npm:18.3.1
   ├─ Instances: 1
   ├─ Version: 18.3.1
   │
   └─ Dependencies
      ├─ loose-envify@npm:^1.1.0 → npm:1.4.0
      └─ scheduler@npm:^0.23.2 → npm:0.23.2

Any thoughts on this issue? References, or ideas? I'm feeling stuck. Thank you.

did you add "use client" on top of your useModal custom hook?

Can you share full code please?

I fixed this issue. I had a nested project that had a dependency of react and react-dom. I changed this to a peer dependency like so:
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.3",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  },

I now recall moving this out of peerDependencies to fix a test build that required all deps to be in node_modules... it's been a month or two of upgrades.
I had not thought that an identically-versioned nested dependency would generate a separate instance of React... wtf.
Does anybody else feel overwhelmed by the state of the JS package management and build ecosystem? ✋
